# Speedbar how to add support for custom source files?

Tags: emacs, emacs-speedbar

I want Speedbar to display outlines (list of variables, functions and other "interesting" objects") I have in source files it doesn't understand yet. I have code to generate TAGS for the sources in question, where should I look for a hook / configuration to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `speedbar-add-supported-extension` function to add new files that speedbar doesn't understand by default.

From `speedbar.el`:

> You should use the function 'speedbar-add-supported-extension' to add a new extension at
>   runtime, or use the configuration dialog to set it in your .emacs file.
>   If you add an extension to this list, and it does not appear, you may
>   need to also modify 'completion-ignored-extension' which will also help
>   file completion.

In addition to that, you may want to teach speedbar how to parse the tags for this new file using `speedbar-fetch-etags-parse-list`. For a C/C++ style language with a file extension `.foo` you might want to do something like this.

```lisp
(speedbar-add-supported-extension ".foo")
(add-to-list 'speedbar-fetch-etags-parse-list
    '("\\.foo" . speedbar-parse-c-or-c++tag))
```